# Can't load System.Resources.Extensions - in .Net Framework

Tags: winforms, exception, typeinitializationexception

I am suddenly getting an error in my code which is a Forms app compiled for .Net Framework 4.6.1. It occurs when I go to create an object that inherits from the TreeView object.

It does very little on top of TreeView.

The exception is:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Resources.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

It has this code:

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
    SendMessage(this.Handle, TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, (IntPtr)TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER, (IntPtr)TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }
```

And does the following in setup:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // LinkTreeView
    // 
    this.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
    this.DrawNode += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(this.LinkTreeView_DrawNode);
    this.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.LinkTreeView_MouseEnter);
    this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.LinkTreeView_MouseMove);
    this.NodeMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.LinkTreeView_NodeMouseClick);
    this.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.LinkTreeView_MouseLeave);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

It has member variables, but they're all standard Forms classes:

```
private Brush disabledBrush;
private Brush foregroundBrush;
private Brush linkBrush;
private Brush visitedBrush;
private Brush backGroundBrush;

private Pen activeLinkPen;
private Pen linkPen;
private Pen visitedLinkPen;

private StringFormat format;

// the delete bitmap out at the end.
private static readonly Bitmap deleteActive;
private static readonly Bitmap deleteDisabled;
private static readonly Rectangle rectDeleteBitmap;
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Was the Project first built on .Net Core maybe? Or a NuGet package went missing? That one or [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) or one of the dependencies. If it was a NuGet package (for 4.6.1), install it again (the main package, I mean).

Comment: One of the libraries it uses was recently built for .Net Core also. But it is still building the .Net Framework version too and that's what I am using - I'm pretty sure (I'll check again).

Comment: I'm hitting this same error while converting a csproj file to the newer SDK style. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to a bug that exists in .net 4.8 and before see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39078

I got it when referencing a library built for .net core 3.1 and .net framework 4.8.

Note that you need to reference the System.Resources.Extensions nuget when targeting both framework and .net core. There is a new project property `<GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources>True</GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources>` that is added so resources bundling works for both.

Workaround (from the bug comments and worked for me) is to add a bindingredirect to app.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Resources.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be [solved](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/50288) in [the 6.0.0 version of the System.Resources.Extensions nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Resources.Extensions/6.0.0)?

Comment: Switched a project targeting .Net Framework 4.6.1 to 4.6.2 and got this error. Adding the binding redirect makes the app run correctly after building in Visual Studio (even if run outside the IDE). However, when I install and run, it fails. I've checked that the installed .config file does indeed have the correct binding redirect. I also tried adding the GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources propery in my csproj file, but when I do that, the app shuts down almost immediately and does not even get as far as reporting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: I see that there are several System DLLs in my release folder not included with the installer, so I'm betting there is some new dependency.

Comment: Wow. I'm an idiot. Forgot to add System.Resources.Extensions to my installer :-)

Comment: Adding the binding redirect solved the issue on my end (I'm using 7.0.0.0 of System.Resources.Extensions in an old Framework 4.7.2 WinForms project).